# Calculating percentage within the SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table that contains two types in information one called `Number_Of_Calls` and another called `Number_Of_Answered`.

Now in my application I want to get how many percentage the `Number_of_answered` are of the `Number_of_calls` and I figured that calculating within the database would be the best way to do it.

However I don't know how to calculate within SQL

So far I have:

```
Select Number_Of_Calls,
       Number_of_answered 
  from table 
 Where Date BETWEEN '2012-09-10' AND '2012-09-11'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In mysql, can you divide one alias, by another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190251/in-mysql-can-you-divide-one-alias-by-another)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select 
Number_of_Calls,
Number_of_Answered,
((Number_of_answered/Number_Of_Calls)*100) as answer_percent,
Date
from table Where Date BETWEEN '2012-09-10' AND '2012-09-11'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but what if i want the get the date aswell? can i do that?

Comment: Yep, just specify it in the list of selected columns.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: i cant seem to make the calculation work :S it says invalid identifier but when i run them as select 
Number_of_Calls,
Number_of_Answered
from table Where Date BETWEEN '2012-09-10' AND '2012-09-11'

i get the right result out

Comment: Post the DDL for the table your querying.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen 1) Just missing comma after `Number_of_Answered`; 2) `Date` is a reserved word, because of this there may be another error `ORA-00936`. Do not use reserved words as columns' names.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Good call on the comma, I missed that.  I'm not sure what to do about the reserved word, it was in the sql they provided.  The funny thing is the answer after mine is also missing the comma.

Comment: @kmb385 i am not at my work station but the Comma should work?

Comment: @kmb385 hey i made it work! but now its telling me that it cant devide with 0 (which makes sence) but what can i do about that?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Given that some time has elapsed and this is a separate issue, I would post a new question asking for help.  This keeps things itemized and you may get others perspective on the issue since your question will be fresh. In the question include your which database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
Number_Of_Calls,
Number_of_answered
((Number_of_answered/Number_Of_Calls)*100.00) as percent
from table_name Where Date BETWEEN '2012-09-10' AND '2012-09-11'
```