# Calculating Percentage when Row can contain 0

Tags: sql, database, oracle, calculated-columns

I have previously asked the following question: [Calculating percentage within the SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726077/calculating-percentage-within-the-sql)

Now i was lucky enough to get a great answer however in my question i did not take into account that my rows could contain zero.

The questions  row where simple:

```
select 
Number_of_Calls,
Number_of_Answered,
((Number_of_answered/Number_Of_Calls)*100) as answer_percent,
Date
from table Where Date BETWEEN '2012-09-10' AND '2012-09-11'
```

However Number_of_answered could be zero (if our company did not answer the calls) so if i want the full number in percentage how do i take 0 into account?

By the way. The database that we use is an Oracle database with PL SQL

Comment: Add to where `AND Number_of_answered > 0`?

Comment: if your number of answered is zero then your answer percent is zero, what is wrong with that?

Comment: @beherenow Actually there is a mistake in my Statement its suppose to be Number_of_calls/ Number_of_answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nullif` function can be used to return null if the divisor is zero.  When SQL encounters a null divisor it forces the entire equation to return null, preventing your error from occurring.

```
select 
Number_of_Calls,
Number_of_Answered,
((Number_of_answered/nullif(Number_Of_Calls,0))*100) as answer_percent,
Date
from table Where Date BETWEEN '2012-09-10' AND '2012-09-11'
```

If you would like to exclude null percentages use the following SQL:

```
select * from(select 
    Number_of_Calls,
    Number_of_Answered,
    ((Number_of_answered/nullif(Number_Of_Calls,0))*100) as answer_percent,
    Date
    from table Where Date BETWEEN '2012-09-10' AND '2012-09-11') alias
where answer_percent is not null;
```

Comment: When i write this i get  S1000(906)[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Comment: Did you copy and paste or transcribe the answer?  Transcribe meaning typed it in?  I'm not seeing any issues with the syntax and can execute a similar statement on my db.

Comment: Here is my statement in my db:select 
ANTAL_KALD,
BESVARET_25_SEK,
((ANTAL_KALD/nullif(BESVARET_25_SEK,0))*100) as answer_percent,
TIDSPUNKT
from table Where TIDSPUNKT BETWEEN '2012-09-10' AND '2012-09-11'

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Excellent!  Good job!

Comment: is there anyway to not include the Null ? like saying if its null then  i dont want to get that row?

Answer (score 3):

```
Case when Number_Of_Calls = 0 
     THEN 0 --or your desired value, maybe 100
     else (Number_of_answered/Number_Of_Calls)*100 
END as answer_percent
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you mean "Number_Of_Calls" could be zero (thus raising a zero_divide error?) if so do

```
case Number_Of_Calls when 0 then 0 else ((Number_of_answered/Number_Of_Calls)*100) as answer_percent
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood you from your comment you want a rate of answered calls over a period of time, including days when 100% calls were unanswered.

I guess the simpliest approach would be

```
select sum(number_of_answered) / sum (number_of_calls) 
  from table 
 where date between interval_start and interval_end
```

in this case.